# why gurumeditation error coming in vagrant up command

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

i was facing this error and tried all steps but still same error
==> master: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'gurumeditation' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.

Comment: i disable vtx- in machine bios and start and then enable it again because it is needed to create vm but this solution is not good , this is not permanent solution